# Does commutativity imply Associativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations, associativity

Does commutativity imply associativity? I'm asking this because I was trying to think of structures that are commutative but non-associative but couldn't come up with any. Are there any such examples?

NOTE: I wasn't sure how to tag this so feel free to retag it.

Comment: Commutative operations that are associative are the exception. But an important exception! Let $x\ast y=|x-y|$.

Comment: Not even in the presence of an identity element and an opposite, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56016/are-the-axioms-for-abelian-group-theory-independent). In fact, William's answer is already in that post ;)

Comment: The interchange law $(x * y) \cdot (z * w) = (x \cdot z) * (y \cdot w)$, in the presence of a two-sided common unit element, implies commutativity and associativity of $*$ and $\cdot$. (In fact, they have to be the same operation!)

Comment: See my 3 February 2009 sci.math post **A natural example of a commutative, non-associative operator** (see [Google archive version](https://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/65eb9dbc40481683) or [Math Forum archive version](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6594456)) for some examples and references.

Comment: Good old mod arithmetic: Take $n\ge 2$. Then defining $x\ast y := (x\operatorname{mod} n^2)(y\operatorname{mod} n^2)$, we have that $0 = (n\ast n)\ast 1\ne n\ast(n\ast 1) = n^2$.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Consider the operation $(x,y) \mapsto xy+1$ on the integers.

Comment: @marlu Could you explain this some more please? It doesn't say why, or (for people like me who don't know much about maths), what that arrow even means.

Comment: Well, associativity and commutativity are properties of maps $X\times X \to X$ for a set $X$. In other words, such a map takes two elements as an "input" and returns a single element. In my example, the set under consideration is the set of integers and the map sends each pair of integers $(x,y)$ to $xy+1$. Commutativity means $xy + 1 = yx + 1$ for all $x$ and $y$, which is satisfied. Associativity would mean $x(yz+1) + 1 = (xy+1)z+1$ for all $x$, $y$ and $z$, but it's easy to find examples where this equation does not hold, so the operation is not associative.

Comment: But wait, this is unfair — you're considering commutativity under addition, but associativity under both addition and multiplication, they're different operations! ☹

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Commutativity and associativity are properties of a single binary operation; in this case, the operation defined by marlu above. Denoting this operation by, say, the symbol $\odot$, it is clearly commutative since $x \odot y = xy+1 = yx+1 = y \odot x$, but not associative since $(x \odot y) \odot z = (xy+1)z+1 = xyz+z+1 \ne xyz+x+1 = x(yz+1)+1 = x \odot (y \odot z)$ whenever $x \ne z$.

Answer (score 66):

A basic example is the "midpoint" binary operation: $a*b = \frac{a+b}{2}$

In general, if $P(u,v)$ is any polynomial in two variables with rational coefficients, then $x*y = P(x+y,xy)$ is rarely associative - I'd be curious under what conditions on $P$ this operation would be associative.

My example is $P(u,v)=\frac{u}{2}$ and Marlu's example is $P(u,v)=1+v$.

Comment: In general, a symmetric function $P(x,y)$ is rarely associative. You could take $P(x,y)=\arctan xy+e^{(x+y)^9}$, too.

Answer (score 65):

Arguably the most important example of a commutative but non-associative structure is that of finite-precision [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) under addition. `(a + -a) + b` is always equal to `b` but `a + (-a + b)` can differ from `b` since the sum `-a + b` can involve a loss of precision (this is especially true if `a` and `b` are nearly but not quite equal, `-a + b` could work out to `0` even though the corresponding real sum is nonzero). The lack of associativity of floating point arithmetic is a constant complicating factor in numerical analysis.

Comment: This is a nice example, because it reminds us how important these concepts are in practical life, even though we often do not think about them..(+1)

Comment: Yea. Sure, is easy to work with mathematical real numbers. But floating point representations can cause problems - see, for example,  [The Patriot Missile Failure](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html).

Comment: `(a + -a) + b` is also not always equal to `b`. Consider `a = inf`, then the result is NaN. Also depending on your definition of 'equality', if `a = 0` and `b` is `-0` then the result is `0` - with a different sign than `b`.

Answer (score 59):

Consider the commutative operation $\texttt{vs}$ on the set $\{\textbf{rock}, \textbf{paper}, \textbf{scissors}\}$ abbreviated $\{r,p,s\}$ defined by
$$ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
\texttt{vs} & r&p&s\\ \hline
r & r & p & r \\
p & p & p & s \\
s & r & s & s
\end{array}$$
It is not associative since, for example, $$\textbf{paper} \texttt{ vs } (\textbf{scissors} \texttt{ vs } \textbf{rock}) = \textbf{paper}$$
but 
$$(\textbf{paper} \texttt{ vs } \textbf{scissors}) \texttt{ vs } \textbf{rock} = \textbf{rock}.$$

Answer (score 27):

The easiest Jordan algebra is symmetric square matrices with the operation 
$$  A \ast B = (AB + BA)/2,    $$
similar to a Lie algebra but with a plus sign.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra

Answer (score 17):

Let $A = \{e,x,y\}$. Define $\cdot$ on $A$ to be $a\cdot e=a$ for all $a$, $e\cdot a= a$ for all a, and $a\cdot b=e$ for all $a$ and $b$ such that $a\neq e$ and $b\neq e$, (i.e. $a,b \in \{x,y\}$).

This operation is commutative, $e$ is the identity, (everything even has an inverse),  but is not associative since $(x \cdot y) \cdot y = e \cdot y = y$ and $x \cdot (y \cdot y) = x \cdot e = x$.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest examples of commutative but nonassociative operations are the NOR and NAND operations (joint denial and alternative denial) in propositional logic. Quoting from my answer to the question [A conjecture in equational logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983633/a-conjecture-in-equational-logic):

> Namely, the $2$-element structure $\{a,b\}$, where $aa=b$ and $ab=ba=bb=a$, is commutative but not associative; in fact, for any $x\in\{a,b\}$, we have
>   $$(ax)b=b(xa)=a,$$
>   $$a(xb)=(bx)a=b.$$
>   This is the unique (up to isomorphism) binary operation on a $2$-element set which is commutative but not associative; it can be interpreted as either of the truth-functions NOR or NAND.

Comment: Perhaps nonobviously $\texttt{XOR}$ (exclusive disjunction) *is* associative---this is arguably easier to see if you identify it with $+$ on $\Bbb Z / (2 \Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 9):

The NAND is commutative but not associative.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B &  & A \text{ nand } A  & (A \text{ nand } A)  \text{ nand } B  &  & A \text{ nand } B  & A \text{ nand } (A  \text{ nand } B)  \\ \hline
0&0& &1&1& &1&1  \\ \hline
0&1& &1&0& &1&1  \\ \hline
1&0& &0&1& &1&0  \\ \hline
1&1& &0&1& &0&1  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Please excuse ... but I went to the trouble of constructing the truth table ... feel free to remove it.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I would use three variables instead were I you.

Comment: I already mentioned the examples NAND and NOR in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160945/does-commutativity-imply-associativity/1553503#1553503) in 2015, so what was your point?

Answer (score 8):

The arithmetical, geometrical and harmonic mean operations on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R^+}$ and $\mathbb{R_*^+}$ resp.:

$$a*b=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$$

$$a*b=\sqrt{ab}$$

$$a*b=\dfrac{ab}{a+b}$$

**Remark:** the non-associativity of arithmetical mean has a kind of physical interpretation by placing more weight either on the last or on the first term:

$$(a*b)*c=\dfrac{\tfrac{a+b}{2}+c}{2}=\dfrac{a+b+2c}{4}$$

whereas

$$a*(b*c)=\dfrac{2a+b+c}{4}$$

(none of them being equal to $\dfrac{a+b+c}{3}$ !...)

Answer (score 5):

For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $x*y = xy + 1$.

Then * is clearly commutative.

As for associativity,
$$a*(b*c) = a*(bc + 1) = a(bc + 1) + 1 = abc + a + 1$$
$$(a*b)*c = (ab + 1)*c = (ab + 1)c + 1 = abc + c + 1$$
so associativity fails for any triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a \ne c$.

Here's another example . . .

For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $x y = x^2y^2$.

Once again, commutativity is obvious.

For associativity,
$$a*(b*c) = a*(b^2c^2) = a^2(b^2c^2)^2 = a^2b^4c^4$$
$$(a*b)*c = (a^2b^2)*c = (a^2b^2)^2c^2 = a^4b^4c^2$$
so associativity fails if $a,b,c \ne 0$, and $|a| \ne |c|$.

One last example . . .

For $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $x*y = -x-y$.

Commutativity is clear.

For associativity,
$$a*(b*c) = a*(-b-c) = -a-(-b-c) = -a + b + c$$
$$(a*b)*c = (-a-b)*c = -(-a-b)-c = a + b -c $$
so associativity fails if $a \ne c$.

Answer (score 3):

Using mace4 on the assumption `x*y=y*x.` and goal `(x*y)*z=x*(y*z).` gives:

```
% Interpretation of size 2

*(0,0) = 1.
*(0,1) = 0.
*(1,0) = 0.
*(1,1) = 0.

c1 = 0.

c2 = 0.

c3 = 1.
```

i.e. `0*0=0`, `0*1=0`, `1*0=0`, `1*1=0`, with `(x,y,z)=(0,0,1)` being the counter-example.

```
(0*0)*1 = 1*1 = 0
0*(0*1) = 0*0 = 1
```

---

P.S. [Mace4](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/) is a software used for constructing finite models and finding counter-examples.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer uses a "mace4" software that is "not very well known" (euphemism)...

Comment: @JeanMarie so what?

Comment: So, I give you a [+1] to your answer, which is good... but...

Comment: @JeanMarie mais quoi?

Comment: (Thanks for using French :)) You should say more about "mace4" system you use : we have no idea on the category of software it belongs to for example ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I've added a postscriptum.

Comment: The function shown could be considered "neither $x$ nor $y$" if the binary arguments are Booleans.  Thus it compares with the NAND answer (by duality).

Comment: Thanks, @Kenny Lau.

Comment: @bof: You gave a fine Answer, but likely I was comparing the mace4-generated (counter)example here with NAND as discussed [in Bram28's 2017 Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2446513/3111), posted minutes before my Comment.

Answer (score 2):

Given ideals $I$ and $J$ in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over a commutative ring $K$, the ideal product $[I,J]$ defined as the image of the composite $$I \otimes_K J \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{g} \otimes_K \mathfrak{g} \xrightarrow{[-, -]} \mathfrak{g}$$ is commutative, but not associative in general. It is easy to see why, because the ideal product is given by $$[I,J] \equiv \{ \Sigma_{i=0}^n [x_i, y_i] \mid \text{$x_i \in I$, $y_i \in J$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$} \},$$
and $[x,y]=-[y,x]$, but the bracket is not associative in general.

Answer (score 1):

For our example the carrier set will be the set ${\Bbb Z}^{\Bbb Z}$ of all functions from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$.

For any two function $f, g \in {\Bbb Z}^{\Bbb Z}$ we can form the pointwise sum, $f + g: n \mapsto f(n) + g(n)$.

We have the (left) bilateral shift operator $T$ on ${\Bbb Z}^{\Bbb Z}$,

$\tag 1 T: (a_k)_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mapsto (a_{k+1})_{k=-\infty}^\infty$

We define a binary operation $\oplus$ on the set ${\Bbb Z}^{\Bbb Z}$ as follows,

$\tag 2 (f,g) \mapsto f \oplus g = T \circ (f+g)$

This binary operation is commutative but not associative; it satisfies

$\tag 3 f \oplus g =  h \oplus k \; \text{ iff } \; f + g = h + k$