# Real life examples of commutative but non-associative operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations, associativity

I've been trying to find ways to explain to people why associativity is important.
Subtraction is a good example of something that isn't associative,  but it is not commutative.

So the best I could come up with is paper-rock-scissors; the operation takes two inputs and puts out the winner (assuming they are different).

So (paper rock) scissors= paper scissors = scissors,

But paper (rock scissors)= paper rock = paper.

This is a good example because it shows that associativity matters even outside of math.

What other real-life examples are there of commutative but non-associative operations? Preferably those with as little necessary math background as possible.

Comment: Your question is distinct, but these two questions are closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327422/is-all-algebraic-commutative-operation-always-associative and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160945/does-commutativity-imply-associativity/160950.

Comment: The most "real-life" (or otherwise simplest) examples from the linked questions seem to be the operations: sending $(A,B)$ to the midpoint of $A$ and $B$, and $(x,y) \mapsto xy +1$ on the integers.

Comment: Mixing chemicals in chemistry is not necessarily associative when considering physical factors: i.e. suspensions/colloids. I do not know of an example where chemically mixing is not associative. The midpoint operation can be visualized with strings, where $(A,B)$ means you cut (or otherwise mark) at the midpoint of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What's this "real-life" thing?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622348/non-associative-commutative-binary-operation/1623111#1623111); is "nor" not a real life example?

Answer (score 23):

Let $\circ$ be the "function" of $a$ and $b$ having a child. Then
$$(a\circ b)\circ c \neq a\circ(b\circ c),$$
where I assume asexual reproduction...

Comment: I am not sure whether a +1 is in order for a good answer, or a -1 for suggestions of incest. Very good example for why associativity is important.

Comment: @Eric thanks, but it only works fine for asexual reproduction...

Comment: I was interpreting as $\circ$ takes two people and outputs their child. Then $(a\circ b)\circ c$ is the child made by (the child of $a$ and $b$) and $c$. And $a\circ(b\circ c)$ is the child of $a$ and (the child of $b$ and $c$). Taking $a$, $b$, and $c$ as the top nodes, you may draw the family tree, and see that in terms of DNA, the operation is not associative. I suppose it is not incest actually though, but does suggest a wide age gap between couples.

Comment: Since $x\circ y$ is not defined for $x$ and $y$ both male or both female, $\circ$ is clearly a halfoperation over the set of human beings.

Comment: This does not assume asexual reproduction if $a$ and $c$ are of one sex and $b$, $a\circ b$ and $b\circ c$ are of another. It also does not contain an incest if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are genetically unrelated, because then $a\circ b$ is unrelated to $c$ and $a$ is unrelated to $b \circ c$. It only implies relatively large (at least one generation) age differences.

Comment: @Danijel I edited my post...

Answer (score 18):

The averaging operation, defined by $$a\oplus b= \frac{a+b}2$$ is commutative but not associative.

Answer (score 13):

What about commas?

> Brian Rushton finds inspiration in cooking, his family and his dog.

vs.

> Brian Rushton finds inspiration in cooking his family and his dog.

Shows pretty well how associativity makes a difference.

Comment: I've rolled this answer back to its previous state, I'm 99% sure the previous edit was not at all appropriate -- perhaps as a comment, but certainly not as a revised answer.

Comment: @pjs36, thank you. I also think that it wasn't appropriate. For reference, the  comment was "Shouldn't we care about the fact that the word 'cooking' has two different meanings (noun vs verb or object vs process) in the two sentences?"

Comment: Sure! Yes, it took me a while to piece it together, but *something* seemed off. It was a pretty good comment, just not a good revision!

Answer (score 9):

Mixing (same amount of ) primary colors:

(red + blue ) + blue = purple + blue = blue purple,

red +  ( blue  + blue ) = red + blue = purple.

Comment: Do you mean light or paint?

Comment: I was thinking about paint on a canvas

Comment: For certain inputs that is associative. (cyan+magenta)+yellow=black=cyan+(magenta+yellow).

Comment: And also, if you took two grams of blue paint and one gram of red paint, the end result would be the same shade no matter the order you mixed them in.

Comment: For certain inputs mixing can be associative, I agree (due to complementary colors), but in general it is not. And yes...mixing of the same amount of color :)

Comment: @Boluc Papuccuoglu yes and shouldn't it be the answer _mixing equal amounts of primary colors_?

Comment: Also: water+(flour+yeast)$\ne$(water+flour)+yeast !!