# A conjecture in equational logic

Tags: universal-algebra

In an algebra with a single binary operation g, is there a single equational identity that generates the same set of identities as the set {g(x,y)=g(y,x) , g(g(x,y),z)=g(x,g(y,z))}? My conjecture is that there isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use multiplicative notation for the operation, i.e., I write $xy$ instead of $g(x,y)$.

**In the language of one binary operation, there is no single identity which is equivalent to the conjunction of the associative and commutative laws.**

**Case I.** Each side of the supposed identity contains at least two multiplications, i.e., the identity is of the form $(t_1t_2)t_3=(t_4t_5)t_6$ or $(t_1t_2)t_3=t_4(t_5t_6)$ or $t_1(t_2t_3)=t_4(t_5t_6)$ for some terms $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6$.

The commutative law is not a consequence of such an identity, or even the set of all such identities. To see this, consider the $4$-element structure $\{a,b,c,d\}$ with multiplication defined so that $ab=c$, while $xy=d$ whenever $x\ne a$ or $y\ne b$. In this structure $ab\ne ba$, while both sides of all the identities under consideration evaluate to $d$.

**Case II.** One side of the supposed identity contains at most one multiplication, i.e., the identity is of the form $xy=t$ or $xx=t$ or $x=t$ for some term $t$.

We may assume that the identity is a **consequence** of the associative and commutative laws, and so it holds in the structure $(\mathbb Z,+)$. Therefore, each variable occurs the same number of times on either side of the equality sign. This leaves us with the identities $xy=yx$,$\ xy=xy$,$\ xx=xx$, and $x=x$, none of which implies the associative law. Namely, the $2$-element structure $\{a,b\}$, where $aa=b$ and $ab=ba=bb=a$, is commutative but not associative; in fact, for any $x\in\{a,b\}$, we have
$$(ax)b=b(xa)=a,$$
$$a(xb)=(bx)a=b.$$
This is the unique (up to isomorphism) binary operation on a $2$-element set which is commutative but not associative; it can be interpreted as either of the truth-functions NOR or NAND.